# Adding to a variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am trying to add a variable depending on the answer of the user gives e.g

```
points = 0
print("Do you have a cat or a dog?")
response = input()
if response == 'Dog' points=+1
elif response == 'Cat' points=+2
```

"points" is the variable and it is 0 right now so depending on the answer the user gives how can i add a number to the variable so that it can change from 0 to either 1 or 2

Comment: use a dictionary to associate animal name with the number of points.

Answer (score 1):

```
points = 0
print("Do you have a cat or a dog?")
response = input()
if response == 'Dog' :points+=1
elif response == 'Cat':points+=2
```

I think you have to put += instead of =+.

Or maybe, it's simplier

```
points=points+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
points = 0
print("Do you have a cat or a dog?")
response = input()
if response == 'Dog' points=+1
elif response == 'Cat' points=+2
```

the computer sees this as

```
points = 0
print("Do you have a cat or a dog?")
response = input()
if response == 'Dog' 0=+1
elif response == 'Cat' 0=+2
```

because points = 0, so when you "add" to it, 
    points=+1
you are adding one to nothing and are not effecting the points value.
A better way of doing this is
    points = points+1
and the computer sees that as 
    0 = 0+1
or 
    points+=1
to make it easier

Answer (score -1):

```
points = 0
print("Do you have a cat or a dog?")
response = input()
if response == 'Dog': points=+1
elif response == 'Cat': points=+2

print points
```

Try this code, your if sentence have not *:*

Comment: The question asks how to _add_ to a variable; this solution doesn't use addition.

Comment: @BryanOakley give me an example